# jQuery selector to find TR that contains TD INPUT with specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Ok, this seems like it should be a simple question, but the answer eludes me.  I have a form that is built from JSON data from which I build a table of 3 rows and 14 columns each containing an INPUT text control.

When the value in any of those controls changes I need to find the containing row whose input control in the first column equals a specific year.

Here is a sample of the markup:

```
<table id="MyTable">
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="changeHandled"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="changeHandled" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The selector I've tried is: `#MyTable tr:has('input[value="{year}"]')` and a few dozen variations.

I replace the `{year}` string with the year value I'm searching for, so it ends up looking like: `#MyTable tr:has('input[value="2014"]')`

I believe it may be due to the fact the values are set through code initially, because if I use `#MyTable tr:has('input')` it returns all of the rows.

Because of maintainability I don't want to hardcode the path and just say `$(this).closest("tr")...` in javascript code.

Any idea how to retrieve a reference to the TR containing an input with a specific value?  If my code is correct, do I need to do something different when setting the value via code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector `$('#MyTable tr:has(input[value="2014"])')` will only work if the `input` element has a hardcoded `value` attribute with a value of `2014`. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/7dpomtoq/).

If you are trying to select an `input` element without a hardcoded `value` attribute, then you could filter over the elements and return `input` elements whose value equals `2014`. Depending on your needs, you could listen to the `input` or `change` event.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xn87rf65/)

```
$('#MyTable input').on('input change', function () {
    $tr = $('#MyTable tr input:first').filter(function () {
        return this.value === '2014' || $(this).attr('value') === '2014';
    }).closest('tr');
});
```

Comment: This question was so long ago I don't even recall how I fixed it, but re-reading it your solution will in fact work so I've marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use a plan JS solution it might look like:

```
function getRowByYear(year) {
  var table = document.getElementById('MyTable');
  var row, rows = table.rows;
  var input;

  for (var i=0, iLen=rows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    input = rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

    if (input.value == year) {
      return rows[i];
    }
  }
}
```

and would probably run very much faster than a jQuery selector.

However, since you say "*When the value in any of those controls changes…*" then perhaps you are using a change event, so you can simply get the input from which the event was dispatched (*this* within the listener) and go up to the nearest row.

Answer (score 0):

Though I agree that vanilla JS would be more efficient, I think filtering is too expensive? I'd go with listening for the change event and finding the closest row:

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'change', 'input[type="text"]', function(){
  var theRow = $( this ).closest( 'tr' );
  // Do what you need to with theRow
} );
```

Comment: Yes but this doesn't trigger on click events, just when a text input is changed. Or he might even do it on blur. But I wouldn't run through every input and check its value whenever one input changes - that's expensive and not necessary when just wanting to change/check the row of the changed input.